Lignite deposits in Texas
I was looking at a map of lignite deposits in Texas
http://www.texascenter.org/almanac/Energy/7.1.MAP.coal.HTML
I am wondering if those are the washed up debris lines from the Chicxulub tsunami?

Sorry but no. The Jackson-Yegua group, pink and purple on your map, lignites are upper Eocene deposits that are dated to 38Ma or younger, so in no way related to the end Cretaceous, the Chicxulub impact was at c.65Ma. What we're probably seeing is wetland deposits that were buried as the shoreline shifted with ice cover.
The Wilcox group, green and blue on your map, while dated to the Paleocene was deposited post K-T boundary. It probably wouldn't exist without the Chicxulub impact, the death of so much ground cover freed up a lot of sediment that was then eroded and deposited as a series of "sand pulses", the Wilcox is the first of these. Lignites at the base of the formation could be tsunami debris but the coal measures of the Wilcox group are interbedded within the massive sandstone deposits.
